# Excel how to find the first and last index of the cells containing words(or condition)

Tags: excel

How to find the first and last index of the cells containing word `haha` or `hehe.` I know the method with additional column near the original column that is

`=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($Q$1:$R$1,A1)))` `Q1,R1` is `haha, hehe`

then use `=MATCH(1,INDEX(A:A,0,1),0)` to find the first one(actually, don't know the index of last one, only know use `LOOKUP` to find the value of last cell)

But now, the original column is dynamic, it is not allowed to add the auxiliary column

Is there any effective way to find the index of last and first cell, note that is `index`! not the ·value·!
Here is the sample data:

`12, 13, asdhehe34, 23, we4haha, w3heheeq, 23haha, 234, hehehaha2, hehe43, 23`

then the first one is `asdhehe34`, the last one si `hehe43.` But it is not allowed to add the auxiliary column `0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0`(`0` not contain, `1` contain) to find the first `1` and last `1`, since the data of column is dynamic, we can only select the whole `A:A`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your sheet structure. Assuming you data starts from `A1` cell. Use the following formulas to get first and last cell index number for `haha`.

To get first cell index number use...

```
=SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$12="haha",ROW($A$1:$A$12),""),1)
```

To get last cell index number use...

```
=LARGE(IF($A$1:$A$12="haha",ROW($A$1:$A$12),""),1)
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formulas as it is an array formula.

[image]

Comment: You have to modify the formulas if data starts from different cells.

Comment: Sorry, I mean containing `haha` or `hehe`, not exactly is, e.g `abhahae` `cchehea`

Comment: Can you put some sample data? So that I can understand better.